# How to check Palindromic lists

Tags: c++

I would like to know how I can write a function to determine if the list read in from the bellow code is palindromic? e.g if say the list of numbers is 123456 the program will print out "This list is not a palindrome" and if the list is say 12321 then it would print out "This list is a palindrome".

any help would be appreciated.

```
void popArray(int array1[]) {
    ifstream infile("TEST1.TXT");
    if (!infile) {
        cout << "Can't open file: " << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        infile >> array1[i];
        cout << setw(2) << array1[i];
    }
}
void reverseList(int array1[]) {
    for (int x = 9; x > -1; x--) {
        cout << setw(2) << array1[x];
    }
}
```

Comment: A simple test for a palindrome is to reverse your 'list' (actually it's an array) and if the two lists are the same then it's a palindrome. Looks like you have some of the code to do that above, so why not have a go.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using an index `i` and have it go from `0` to `size/2`. Then inside the loop comparing `list[i] == list[(size - 1) - i ]`.

Comment: You want to compare `list[i]` and `list[size-1-i]`.

Comment: Good point. I should really wake up before answering questions on SO.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool isPalindrome(int array1[], int size) {
    for (int i = 0, j = size - 1; i < j; ++i, --j)
        if (array1[i] != array1[j])
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This isn't very size agnostic.

Answer (score 0):

You can even try something this way

```
for(i=0;i<(size/2);i++)
 if(b[i] - b[size-i] !=0 )
  break;

if(i<(size/2))
 cout<<"Not palindrome";
else
 cout<<"palindrome";
```

assuming `b` is a temp copy of the  original array

Comment: why using two indexes when you can use only one and compare `b[i]` and `b[size - i]`?

Comment: @Marius Ya. That is actually more sensible. Updated.

Comment: @Marius :P Oops, Yes i guess i need a cup of coffee